# How to shorten the amount of characters in the preview snipet of my wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

I want to shorten the amount of characters displayed  in the preview or "read more" area of my main blog page.  Right now it's displaying about 100 characters and I want to shorten it to around 50.  I'm using a wordpress theme.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: The preview length of the posts main page.  The snipet of the blog before it says read more.  Not sure where to adjust this.  Right now it's showing way too much of the blog post on my home page

Comment: It's funny that everyone is assuming `the_excerpt()` is being used, or is even the problem...There's another possible culprit, [the <!--more--> quicktag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Customizing_the_.22more.E2.80.A6.22_text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the wordpress.org [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More), when you edit your post you can type `<!--more-->` at the point of the text you want the excerpt to end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter to get specified number of words:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20; //20 words
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

From [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length).

**OR**

if you want to set the number of characters:

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'my_excerpt');
function my_excerpt($param) {
    return substr($param, 0, 50) . "...";
}
```